# Which User Profile Service Application Proxy is the active one?

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service-app, ups

I have two User Profile Service Applications (UPSA) and two proxies. But since SharePoint doesn’t allow two proxies, I have to figure out which of the two proxies is the one that is working and which one creates the error 6398 in the Event Viewer every minute. I need to delete the proxy that shouldn’t be there.

It all started when I migrated the UPSA from a 2010 environment and I also needed a second UPSA (on a different app server) pointing to another Active Directory which doesn’t have ADFS between the production AD and the test AD. I don’t need to synchronize against the production AD, but I want the profiles still in my farm for reference in test. This setup is OK according to [Spence Harbar](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c922d0a8-db7f-4bdd-87a2-686c836bf406/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-user-profile-service-applications-on-a-single-server-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious).

In Central Admin it looks like the following:

[image]

I’m currently running a full sync against the test AD. It shows both on my new Manage Profile Service: UPSA page (from the 2013 UPSA)

[image]

... and in the Synchronization Service Manager (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe)

[image]

In the timer job history, the incremental synchronization is failing, but I’m actually running a full sync now, so it may be working when the full sync has finished. The 2013 proxy incremental synchronization isn’t running at all – which may indicate that it isn’t in use.

[image]

I’ve managed to get the different proxies using these commands:

```
$saproxy2010 = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy -Identity 86138300-a350-437b-b045-4f596ea08efb
$saproxy2013 = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy -Identity ae44bbc8-03cd-417c-8367-99892874a3e8
```

I also found the property `.IsSynchronizationRunning` to run on my created instances. I’m guessing, but I’m not sure that it is actually the 2010 proxy that is running (since it’s the one created first) and not the 2013 proxy. Is this true or are there other ways I can check which proxy is running and which is failing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

When you see two UPSA on the Service Application page, what if you click on the each service application and on next page check what is the status of the Sync(on left site column). you will see either idle or running.

even job is saying incremental synchronization but it will run full sync if it requires. Their is no separate timer job name for User Profile Full sync. Check the history of the incremental synchronization?

Both UPSA having sync on different server(you cant have two sync on one server), you can check the MIISclient on both servers.

But looks like SharePoint 2010 is working UPSA.

Comment: +1 The 2010 version isn't provisioned, and the 2013 is Idle. What puzzles me is that the 2013 proxy isSyncronizationRunning returns false and the 2010 proxy returns nothing (implying true). Since I ran the sync on 2013 I guess it's using the 2010 proxy, since it's the only incremental job in history, which still fails. Odd too me.

Comment: what you mean not provision? can you see the connection under 2010 UPSA? becuase if no connection then timer job should not schedule. can you search the user from Both UPSA?run this command and see where the upsa instane is online...Get-SPServiceinstance | where {$_.TypeName -like "User Prof
ile*"}

Comment: I get the following: User Profile Synchronization ... Online; User Profile Service             Online; User Profile Synchronization ... Disabled; 
User Profile Service             Disabled

Comment: So if i delete the disabled synchronisation - I'm safe?

Comment: that's mean only one UPSA having the sync connection.  now check from Centeral admin which UPSA have the connection configured and also sync timer job configures

Comment: The connection is only available in 2013, but timer jobs are active on both UPSA. I guess a simple test with disabling the 2010 will fix the issue?

Comment: disable the timer job for the 2010 and start a sync from 2013 UPSA.